# Changing cursor type with stored procedure in ASP

Tags: stored-procedures, asp-classic, ado, recordset

Using ASP, I want to call a stored procedure that returns a recordcount.

I understand that I have to change the cursor type to adOpenKeyset or adOpenStatic to return a recordcount.

What I don't understand is how to modify my vbscript so that it changes the cursor type when calling the procedure.

currently I say
cm.commandtype = adCmdStoredProc
.....
rs = cm.execute

I suspect I need to add a parameter to the cm.execute but I cant figure out what to add and how to add it.

Thanks

DMD

Answer (score 1):

Use the Open method on your recordset instead.  Not 100% sure on the syntax, but something like:

```
rs.Open cm, , adOpenStatic
```

Comment: This seems correct.  You can use Execute to say, create a log, but if you want to also return the log you created, you would instead rs.open and use a recordset.  Or in this case, you want to count and then also select the result , so you will want a recordset.

Answer (score 0):

Dzejms is right, but you should put also this line `oRecordSet.CursorLocation = CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient` before `rs.Open cm, , adOpenStatic`

Here is my complete solution:

```vbs
    '>>> ---------------- global declarations ---------------- >>>
    Option Explicit
    Option Base 0
    
    Public ogADODB As New ADODB.Connection ' global variable for performance reason
    
    Public Type tError
      sDescription As String
      sHelpContext As Long
      sHelpFile As String
      cLastDllError As Long
      cNumber As Long
      sSource As String
    End Type
    '<<< ---------------- global declarations ---------------- <<<
    
    
    Sub Test__fnReadSQL()
      Dim oError As tError, oRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset, sSQLSelect As String
      sSQLSelect = "select * from [dbo].[YOUR_TABLE]"
      'sSQLSelect = "[dbo].[sp_STORED_PROCEDURE]"
      oError = fnReadSQL(sSQLSelect, oRecordSet)
      If oError.cNumber <> 0 Then Err.Raise Number:=oError.cNumber, Description:=oError.sDescription & " " & vbCrLf & sSQLSelect, Source:=oError.sSource, HelpFile:=oError.sHelpFile, HelpContext:=oError.sHelpContext
        
      ' do something with your oRecordSet
        
    End Sub
    
    
    Public Function fnReadSQL(sSQLCommand As String, oRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset) As tError ' sSQLCommand can be "select field1, field2, .. from [dbo].[YOUR_TABLE]" or "[dbo].[YOUR_TABLE]" or "[dbo].[StoredProcedure]"
      Dim oCommand As ADODB.Command, sConnectionString As String
    
      On Error GoTo LABEL_Error
      If ogADODB.State = ObjectStateEnum.adStateClosed Then ' for performance reason
        sConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;SERVER=" & sCONST__Server & ";Trusted_Connection=yes;Database=" & sCONST__Database & ";DataTypeCompatibility=80;" 'Windows authentication
        ogADODB.ConnectionTimeout = 300
        ogADODB.Open sConnectionString
      End If
    
      Set oCommand = New ADODB.Command
      oCommand.ActiveConnection = ogADODB
      oCommand.CommandType = CommandTypeEnum.adCmdUnknown 'autodetection of "select" or "stored procedure"
      oCommand.CommandText = sSQLCommand
      Set oRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset
      oRecordSet.CursorLocation = CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient ' this line of code is necessary if you want to use: CursorType = adOpenStatic
      oRecordSet.Open oCommand, , CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly
      Exit Function
    
    LABEL_Error:
      fnReadSQL.sDescription = Err.Description
      fnReadSQL.sHelpContext = Err.HelpContext
      fnReadSQL.sHelpFile = Err.HelpFile
      fnReadSQL.cLastDllError = Err.LastDllError
      fnReadSQL.cNumber = Err.Number
      fnReadSQL.sSource = Err.Source
    End Function
```